# Java - Reading Tensorflow model (pb file) from HDFS

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I see that `SavedModelBundle.load` does not read from HDFS.
I am doing the following to read file from HDFS as `Byte array` and import it as graph.

```
hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(configuration.get("fs.defaultFS")), configuration);
    if (hdfs.exists(location)) {
        FSDataInputStream hdfsInputStream = hdfs.open(location);
        int length = (int) hdfs.getFileStatus(location).getLen();
        byte[] model = new byte[hdfsInputStream.available()];
        hdfsInputStream.read(model);

        hdfsInputStream.close();
        final Graph g = new Graph();
        g.importGraphDef(model);
        Session session = new Session(g);
}
```

I have also tried with `hdfsInputStream.readfully(model)`. It gives same following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid GraphDef
at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method)
at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:130)
at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:114)
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a Java equivalent of `SavedModelBundle.load` for HDFS?
2. What is the alternative? How can I read `.pb` file as `byte array` and import as tensorflow graph correctly?

Note: All of the above works fine if I read model directory from local file system using `SavedModelBundle.load(path)` function. From local, I am not able to correctly read byte array and convert to graph. However, reading `bundle` works fine and give correct outputs.